# Creating files and folders with python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and i'm trying to make a file, move the current script into that file and run it but i keep getting the same problem, it creates a folder, moves the file but when I open the script, it makes a new folder and moves the file. so you'll end up with the file directory being: 'C:somefile\someotherfile\newfile\newfile\newfile\script.py'
Please help!
Code:

```
import os
curpath = ('.\\Test.py')
print(curpath)
newpath = ('.\\Example Folder\\')
if not os.path.exists(newpath) and curpath != ('..\\Example Folder\\Test.py'):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
    abspath=os.path.abspath(curpath)
    print(abspath)
    os.rename(abspath, newpath + 'Test.py')
```

EDIT:
When the answer given didn't work I spent 2 days trying to work it out myself (along with the day of trying before I posted). I finally found out the answer!

```
import os
curpath = __file__.lower()
abspath=os.path.abspath(curpath)
newpath = ('.\\example folder\\')
notpath = '..\\example folder\\'
if not os.path.exists(newpath) and not os.path.exists(notpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)
    os.rename(abspath, '.\\example folder\\test.py')
```

Comment: `curpath != ('..\\Example Folder\\Test.py')` will always evaluate to true, because curpath is set as `curpath = ('.\\Test.py')` and is never changed. These are strings, not file locations, so `'.\\Test.py'` will never equal `'C:\\<enter abs filepath>\\Test.py'`

Comment: so how do i make sure it wont create a bunch of folders?

Comment: set `curpath = __file__.lower()` and change the if to `and curpath != 'c:\\<enter full abs path>\\example folder\\test.py'.lower():`.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're trying to do. What you call 'the current script' is the running script? Which copies itself and calls itself again forever?

Answer (score 1):

`curpath != ('..\\Example Folder\\Test.py')` will always evaluate to true, because `curpath` is set as `curpath = ('.\\Test.py')` and is never changed. These are strings, not file locations, so `'.\\Test.py'` will never equal `'C:\\<enter abs filepath>\\Test.py'`

What you should do is:

Replace `curpath = ('.\\Test.py')` with `curpath = __file__.lower()`

And replace

```
if not os.path.exists(newpath) and curpath != ('..\\Example Folder\\Test.py'):
```

with

```
if not os.path.exists(newpath) and curpath != 'c:\\<enter full abs path>\\example folder\\test.py'.lower():
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> curpath != ('..\Example Folder\Test.py') will always evaluate to
>   true, because curpath is set as curpath = ('.\Test.py') and is never
>   changed. These are strings, not file locations, so '.\Test.py' will
>   never equal 'C:\\Test.py'
>
> What you should do is:
>
> Replace curpath = ('.\Test.py') with curpath = **file**.lower()
>
> And replace
>
> if not os.path.exists(newpath) and curpath != ('..\Example
>   Folder\Test.py'): with
>
> if not os.path.exists(newpath) and curpath != 'c:\\example folder\test.py'.lower():

for the "c:\(enter full abs path)" could i do something like:

```
path='.'
abpath=os.path.abspath(path)
and curpath != abpath + '\\example folder\test.py'.lower():
```

if not then idk how to do it as idk how i would get the full abs path because someone could have it in docs and someone else could have it in downloads

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work, as (as well as a missing escaping ` \ ` in your final line), this will also always evaluate to true, as `os.path.abspath('.')` is the exact same as `__file__.lower()`, meaning that `curpath` would always equal `abspath`, so it would never equal `abspath + <anything>`. The thing about this specific code is that you HAVE to enter the directory manually, because there is no way for the code to know whether you want it to copy out of that directory or not without manual input